# android HTTP POST fail

Tags: java, android, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to connect and post to a simple java webservice, running the post's URL from chrome succeeded, but android code skip the following lines (without throwing errors), but the webservice doesn't accept the post

```
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(setFacebookEventsAddress+userId+"/"+accesstoken);  
            post.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

the webservice method signature handling the above request:

```
    @GET
    @Path("setData/{user_id}/{accessToken}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON+ ";charset=utf-8")
    public String setData(@PathParam("user_id")  String user_id,
                                @PathParam("accessToken")  String accessToken) {
```

since I manage to post throw my browser, anyone can help with what's wrong with my android code?

Comment: `setFacebookEventsAddress` is it variable? sounds like method name...

Comment: What's the error? Maybe you miss a "/" between `setFacebookEventsAddress` and `userId`

Comment: I'm not getting an error, it's seems to execute this lines but i'm not getting any response on server side, as for setFacebookEventsAddress:

static final String setFacebookEventsAddress=SERVER_ADDRESS+"/setFacebookEvents/";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        URL url = new URL(setFacebookEventsAddress+userId+"/"+accesstoken);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();
        ja = readStream(con.getInputStream());
```

Using HttpURLConnection instead of HttpPost did the trick for me, thanks for all the helpers!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to say with any certainty (given the evidence), but my guess would be that the expression

```
setFacebookEventsAddress + userId + "/" + accesstoken
```

is evaluating to a different URL to the one you are using from the web browser.

I suggest that you try the following:

- Turn on request logging on your server, and compare the URLs in the requests being sent.
- Modify your client to print out the response status code and the response body.  The latter is likely to be an error page that will give you more clues.

---

Another possible problem is that your code doesn't appear to be sending any body with the POST request.

---

On revisiting this, the problem was that you were using / trying to do a POST to a web service that you had configured to support GET only.  I expect that if you had looked at the status code you would have found that the response code was "Method not supported".

Comment: I'm taking the url from the variable holding this expression in debug mode, and pasting in my browser works, the webservice expects two strings, which I pass in the url itself, so why would I need a body with my post message beyond setting the header?

Comment: @Ranco - well the fact that you set a Content-type clearly implies / implied that you *intended* to send something in the POST request!!

Comment: yeah =\ figured this out only after